# Is there a way to make Firebase Crashlytics works in remote service?

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics

I have some crashes happen in remote service.

```
<service
    android:name="xxx.AutoCompleteService"
    android:process=":remote">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="xxx.AutoCompleteService" />
    </intent-filter>            
</service>

public class AutoCompleteService extends Service {
...
}
```

The crash is only able to capture by Google Play Console, but not Firebase Crashlytics.

Is there a way to make Firebase Crashlytics works in remote service? As we need to send some additional debug information, to Firebase Crashlytics to make debugging work easier.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize the default FirebaseApp instance in your remote service's onCreate.

```
 override fun onCreate() {
    super.onCreate()
    FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this)
```

Force test failure to submit an app crash report

```
  throw RuntimeException("Test Crash")
```

Go to the Crashlytics dashboard in the Firebase console to see the test failure.